# How many different strings of lights can be created by placing 40 coloured lights on a horizontal string?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

How many different strings of lights can be created by placing 40 coloured lights on a horizontal string if 12 of them are red, 6 are blue, 14 are green and 8 are yellow? Assume that lights of the same colour are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Think about combinations. Pick 12 positions of 40 that will be red, pick 6 out of the remaining 40-12 that will be blue, and pick 14 out of the remaining 40-12-6 that will be green. The rest will have to be yellow.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply permutations with repeated elements, so directly use the appropriate formula to get $\dfrac{40!}{12!6!14!8!}$