# Why was I wrong on this permutation / combination / multinomial problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: We want to make a string of Christmas light to string across a room. The string
contain 36 lights. There are 10 red bulbs, 12 blue bulbs, 10 green bulbs, and
4 yellow bulbs. How many visually distinguishable light strings can we create?
[Similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761545/permutations-and-combination).

**My Attempt:**

Red = R, Blue = B, Green = G, Yellow = 4, then the string of lights can be represented:

RRRRRRRRRRBBBBBBBBBBBBGGGGGGGGGGYYYY

The number of permutations of this string is $${36!}\over{10!12!10!4!}$$
But this is apparently wrong.

**Textbook solution:**

There are $C(36, 10)$ ways to choose the positions for the red bulbs. There are
$C(36 − 10, 12) = C(26, 12)$ ways to choose the positions for the blue bulbs.
There are $C(14, 10)$ ways to choose the positions for the green bulbs. There
are $C(4, 4)$ ways to choose the positions for the yellow bulbs.

Hence,

$C(36, 10)C(26, 12)C(14, 10)C(4, 4) = {{36!}\over{10!12!14!4!}}$

Now $${{36!}\over{10!12!10!4!}} > {{36!}\over{10!12!14!4!}}$$

However, I'm failing to see where the extra cases are coming from. Where is the discrepency in my approach to this problem?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Let me type it out.

Comment: Please notify me when you've finished, then I'll convert my downvote to upvote.

Comment: The book ans is wrong, the denominator denotes $40$ lights

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會  He has done so.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for info.  Status updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C(36,10)C(26,12)C(14,10)C(4,4) = $$\frac{36!}{26!10!} * \frac{26!}{14!12!} * \frac{14!}{4!10!} * \frac{4!}{0!4!} = \frac{36!}{10!12!10!4!}$$

Comment: Can you explan your answer a bit in words?

Comment: There are total 36 positions. Out of these 36 positions 10 positions can be chosen in C(36,10) ways.  This leaves 36-10 = 26 positions.  From these 26 positions 12 position can be chosen with C(26,12) ways and so on.   Answer will be the same if first 12 positions are chosen then 10 etc.  C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In fact, there's a mistake in OP's equation $$C(36, 10)C(26, 12)C(14, 10)C(4, 4) = {{36!}\over{10!12!14!4!}}$$, and you're suggesting that the $14$ in the denominator should actually be $10$.  Some explanation in words would clarify things.  Please consider using display style `$$` instead of inline style `$` for longer equations next time, so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Book answer has a typo and OP's method is right.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This makes sense.